# How to pass data from hybrid application to a native application?

Tags: android, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to pass the data from the hybrid app to a native app. Actually, I am trying to achieve SSO between these two applications. Is this is possible or not and if yes then how it can be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you open some Activity then you pass data in `Intent` .. Will this not work for this case ?

Comment: No, we can use intent for native apps but in this case i want transfer data from hybrid app to native app

Answer (score 0):

Sending an Intent would be the way to go.

Other options to share data between apps include:

- Placing a file on the external storage (SD card)
- Let both apps connect to same external webserver
- Include a Content-Provider in your app

It really depends on your use-case, and if you control both apps (and their backend(s))